# How to write SQL 'LIKE' query using '%' where and 'OR' for search operation?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to use SQL LIKE for two different column. Is it possible to use this type of operation?

I have already tried like :

```
$sWhere .= " file_name like '%" . $search_item . "%' OR name like '%" . $search_item . "%' and ";
```

But above code is only working for single case . i want to perform search for both.

this is my code:

```
if (isset($search_item) && $search_item != '') {
      $sWhere .= " file_name like '%" . $search_item . "%' and ";
    }
```

I want to perform search operation using both the column name with one search field.

Response :

```
SELECT a.id, a.file_name, a.file_path,a.upload_type,a.upload_by, b.username,a.addedon 
FROM tbl_asd as a 
INNER JOIN user as b on b.id = a.upload_by 
WHERE a.upload_type = 'asd' and  a.addedon >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1000 DAY ) and (file_name like '%asd%' OR upload_by like '%asd%')  ORDER BY id desc limit 0,10
```

With "No Rows" Found!

Guide me!
Thanks!

Comment: what is that `and` at the end of the statement for?

Comment: concatenating $sWhere and at the end i am using $sWhere = substr($sWhere, 0, strrpos($sWhere, 'and')); to remove that 'and 'from every $sWhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the `OR` part of your `WHERE` clause in parentheses, otherwise you will get more results than you expect (basically any row which has `file_name like '%" . $search_item . "%'`). Use this instead:

```
$sWhere .= " (file_name like '%" . $search_item . "%' OR name like '%" . $search_item . "%') and ";
```

Note that your query as is can leave you open to SQL injection. Ideally you should be preparing a query instead using code similar to this:

```
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE";
$params = array();
$types = '';
if (isset($search_item) && $search_item != '') {
     $query .= " file_name like ? OR name like ? AND ";
     $types .= 'ss';
     array_push($params, "'%$search_item%'", "'%$search_item%'");
}
// add other where clauses in a similar way
// ...
// make sure we have a trailing `WHERE` clause
$query .= '1 = 1';
$stmt = $link->prepare($link, $query) or die($link->error);
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I thought Monday was for optimism and Friday was when we assumed the worst? Have I got that the wrong way around? :-)

Comment: @Himani I have no sample table structure or data to test it against... in what way isn't it working?

Comment: On SO, Monday is far worse than Friday for so many reasons.  Part of the problem being that our Monday morning is still Sunday evening for the West, when people post fairly bad questions.

Comment: hi every one see what i am getting from query response:

Comment: SELECT a.file_name,a.file_path,a.upload_status,a.log_file_path,
                         a.original_file_name,a.upload_type,a.upload_by,
                         b.username,
                         a.addedon FROM tbl_asd as a INNER JOIN user as b on b.id = a.upload_by
                          WHERE a.upload_type = 'abc' and  a.addedon >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1000 DAY ) and (file_name like '%demo%' OR upload_by like '%demo%')  ORDER BY id desc limit 0,10

Comment: with "No rows.".

Comment: @Himani the query looks fine. Can you post some sample data in your question that demonstrates the query not returning the rows you expect?

Comment: $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $search_item = ($request->search_item != "") ? $request->search_item : "";
    $dayData = ($request->dayData != "") ? $request->dayData : "";
    $sWhere = " WHERE a.upload_type = 'Shipment' and  a.addedon >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL $dayData DAY ) and";
    if (isset($search_item) && $search_item != '') {
      $sWhere .= " file_name like '%" . $search_item . "%' and ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr($sWhere, 0, strrpos($sWhere, 'and'));
    $data = $this->model_name->fetchFileData($sWhere);

Comment: @Himani just looking at your query, it looks like `upload_by` should be `username`

Comment: @Himani here's a demo of your query working with `upload_by` switched to `username`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a11bfbfcf53dc3f0d5a0cdf7c561ba2

Comment: @Nick Thank you!  Its very silly mistake from my end .

Comment: @Himani no worries - glad you figured that out. If this did help, please consider marking the answer accepted.

Comment: hi, is there any way to call only one function from multiple function define in interface?

Comment: if i am defining a interface with two or more methods, but i want to use only one from this interface, have you any idea how to set this logic to use only one method ???

Comment: @Himani I'm not sure; I don't think you can provide enough detail in comments. That sounds like it would be worth asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sWhere .= " (file_name like '%" . $search_item . "%' OR name like '%" . $search_item . "%') and ";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use concat for build the proper like condition

```
$sWhere .= " file_name like concat('%', $search_item ,'%') OR name like concat('%', $search_item ,'%') ";
```

(removed  the AND at the end of the string)

Anyway you should take a look at your db driver for prepared statmenent and binding param because the use of PHP in SQL could produce SqlInjection